# Is there a PowerPoint equivalent of Word's ToggleRibbon? Or another way to accomplish the same thing?

Tags: vsto, office-2007, office-2010, powerpoint-2007, powerpoint-2010

[In Office 2007+, you can cause the ribbon to be minimized so that only the tab names are shown, which makes it look a bit like a menu bar. The full ribbon is then only shown when you click on a tab. This ribbon state is what I'm trying to control.]

In the Word 2007+ object model, there's a [ToggleRibbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243911%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method on the `Window` object, that minimizes (or not) the ribbon for that window.

I'm looking for an equivalent method in PowerPoint 2007+, and I can't find one. Is there such a thing, and if not is there another way to achieve it? Apart from using `SendKeys`, that is - don't go there.

Comment: are you creating a power point  addins ?

Comment: Yes. Using VSTO, although if there's a VBA-based solution, I imagine I could "convert" it.

Answer (score -1):

i have implemented in c# with word addins .

you can take help from below link:  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608590.aspx

I have added a button in the ribbon(visual).
in the button click, i have added following code.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Toogle();
        }
```

i have added these code in the `ThisAddIn.cs`:

```
 public void Toogle()
        {
            Word.Window obj = Application.ActiveWindow;
            obj.ToggleRibbon();
        }
```

---

sorry,  `Window.ToggleRibbon()` is present only in word. even it is not present in excel or work. so achieve this, do the following code :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("^{F1}");
        }
```

Hope , this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you mis-understood the question. I'm not trying to show/hide a task pane - I'm trying to minimize or restore the ribbon. I'll update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: you can change height of the user control in the toggle button click

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane.height.aspx

Comment: You're not listening :-)  This is not about task panes. This is about the ribbon. You know, the big thing at the top of the window with buttons on it.

Comment: do you mean to minimize and maximize power point using  button in the ribbon ?

Comment: No! This: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/minimize-the-ribbon-HA010166329.aspx

Comment: I don't want to minimize/maximize the application window, I want to minimize/maximize the RIBBON. Please see the link in my comment above that explains what this means, and how to do this through the UI.

Comment: hope , i have understood the requirement and updated the code ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all your effort, but if you had read the question, you would see that I know all about ToggleRibbon in Word. This method is not available in PowerPoint - which is why I posted this question.

Comment: the only way to achieve your requirement.